# How to make \citet* display full list of authors?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style, author-number

When I am using the `natbib` package with `apalike` bibliography style `\citet*` displays only an abbreviated list of authors, such as `Lemarechal et al. (1995)`. How can I make it display a full list of authors, like `Lemarechal, Nemirovskii, and Nesterov (1995)`, keeping the same or similar bibliography style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting from the natbib documentation, p. 7:

> The starred versions [of `\citet` and `\citep`] can only list the full authors if the `.bst` file supports this feature; otherwise, the abbreviated list is printed.

Below is a minimal example showing that `\citet*` indeed displays a full author list if you use the `plainnat` style, but that `apalike` doesn't support full author lists. Maybe there's a way to embed this feature into `apalike` by hacking the bst-file, but I would use a different style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A01,
  author = {A and B and C and D},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet*{A01}

% No full list of authors with \citet*
% \bibliographystyle{apalike}

% Full list of authors with \citet*
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Do you know any way to hack `apalike` to make this work?

Comment: @Ken: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the `.bst` format and the BibTeX programming language.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did anyone manage to find a hack for this?